# Finding $10^{1001}(\text{mod} \ 1001)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find $10^{1001}(\text{mod} \ 1001)$. It seemed appropriate to use Euler's theorem, as $\text{gcd}(10,1001)=1$. I have found that:

\begin{align}
\phi(1001)&=\phi(7)\phi(11)\phi(13)=720 \ \ \ (\text{where $\phi$} \ \text{denotes Euler's phi-function}) \\
\implies 10^{1001}(\text{mod} \ 1001)&=10^{720+281} (\text{mod} \ 1001) \\
&=1^{720}\cdot10^{281}(\text{mod} \ 1001) \\
&=10^{281}(\text{mod} \ 1001).
\end{align}

I don't know how to solve the problem from here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $10^3\equiv-1\bmod 1001,$ so $10^{3n+2}\equiv(-1)^n100\bmod 1001$